# Short Description Limitation error when importing

Tags: magento, csv, import

I have created csv file with all attributes particularly in 'short_description' field, i added value in table format as below

```
> <table cellspacing=""0"" cellpadding=""0"">   <col width=""215"">  
> <col width=""312"">   <tr>
>     <td colspan=""2"" width=""527"">SALES PACKAGE</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">In The    Box</td>
>     <td width=""312"">Main Unit, User Manual</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td colspan=""2"" width=""527"">GENERAL    FEATURES</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">Brand</td>
>     <td width=""312"">Intel</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">Type</td>
>     <td width=""312"">Processor</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">Processor    Number</td>
>     <td width=""312"">i3-4130</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">Supported    Sockets</td>
>     <td width=""312"">FCLGA1150</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">Number    of Cores</td>
>     <td align=""right"" width=""312"">2</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">Number    of Threads</td>
>     <td align=""right"" width=""312"">4</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">Clock    Speed</td>
>     <td width=""312"">3.4 GHz</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">Intel    Smart Cache</td>
>     <td width=""312"">3 MB</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">DMI2</td>
>     <td width=""312"">5 GT/s</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">Instruction    Set</td>
>     <td width=""312"">64-bit</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">Instruction    Set Extensions</td>
>     <td width=""312"">SSE 4.1/4.2, AVX 2.0</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">Lithography</td>
>     <td width=""312"">22 nm</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">Scalability</td>
>     <td width=""312"">1S Only</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">Max TDP</td>
>     <td width=""312"">54 W</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td colspan=""2"" width=""527"">MEMORY    SPECIFICATIONS</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">Max    Memory Size (dependent on memory type)</td>
>     <td width=""312"">32 GB</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">Memory    Types</td>
>     <td width=""312"">DDR3-1333/1600</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">No. of    Memory Channels</td>
>     <td align=""right"" width=""312"">2</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">Max    Memory Bandwidth</td>
>     <td width=""312"">25.6 GB/s</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">ECC    Memory Supported</td>
>     <td width=""312"">Yes</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td colspan=""2"" width=""527"">GRAPHICS    SPECIFICATIONS</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">Processor    Graphics</td>
>     <td width=""312"">Intel HD Graphics 4400</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">Graphics    Base Frequency</td>
>     <td width=""312"">350 MHz</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">Graphics    Max Dynamic Frequency</td>
>     <td width=""312"">1.15 GHz</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">No. of    Displays Supported</td>
>     <td align=""right"" width=""312"">3</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">Graphics    Video Max Memory</td>
>     <td width=""312"">1.7 GB</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">Additional    Features</td>
>     <td width=""312"">Intel Quick Sync Video; Intel    InTru 3D Technology; Intel Wireless Display; Intel Clear Video HD
> Technology</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td colspan=""2"" width=""527"">EXPANSION    OPTIONS</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">PCI    Express Revision</td>
>     <td align=""right"" width=""312"">3</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">PCI    Express Configurations</td>
>     <td width=""312"">Up to 1x16, 2x8, 1x8/2x4</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">Max No.    of PCI Express Lanes</td>
>     <td align=""right"" width=""312"">16</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td colspan=""2"" width=""527"">ADDITIONAL    FEATURES</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">Features</td>
>     <td width=""312"">Max CPU Configuration: 1;    Package Size: 37.5mm x 37.5mm; Graphics and IMC Lithography: 22 nm; Advanced    Technologies: Hyper-Threading Virtualization Technology, VT-x with
> Extended    Page Tables, Intel 64, Idle States, Enhanced Intel
> SpeedStep Technology, Thermal    Monitoring Technologies; Intel Data
> Protection Technology - AES New    Instructions; Intel Platform
> Protection Technology - Execute Disable Bit</td>   </tr> </table>
```

then i have imported csv file, it displayed following error

> Skipping import row, required field "sku" is not defined.

it supporting for particular limitation, if i added  more than 100 rows of value it shows error, how to solve this

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?